# request not working for android 9 in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

In expo HTTPS API is not working for android 9 with authentication token with body. Any one can help me for solving this issue.

```
Object {
  "fullurl": "https://www.grofirereviews.com:3005/api/user_login",
  "postdata": Object {
    "email": "sandeep@codeplateau.com",
    "password": "123456",
  },
}

Error Message : "Network Error"
```

I used axios library for calling the api

Comment: Please add the code snippet for more details of error.

Comment: Hello rajan screenshot for error -- https://prnt.sc/sf91ld

Answer (score 0):

1. add use of clear text to true in manifest of android
2. also add apache legacy support
   check both on Google.

Answer (score 0):

After search a lot i got the answer. Please follow the link and this will work with expo

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/